# stash embed in expression engine layout not parsing

Tags: stash, ee3, embeds, layouts

I would like to embed my ads by a stash embed inside of my base template, is this not possible to achieve thay way?

`{layout:set name="backgroundAd"}
  {stash:embed context="ech/ads" name="background" stash:seg="{segment_1}"}
  {stash:embed context="ech/ads" name="interstitial_floating" stash:seg="{segment_1}"}
{/layout:set}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you prefix the embeds with 'exp:'

```
{exp:stash:embed}
```

Comment: thx mark, works!